# inserting text area data to database

Tags: php, codeigniter, textarea

i am trying to insert some text written in the text field, there are two field one is ticket which is working fine on the other hand report is not inserted to sql correctly.here is my view code

```
<td><input type='text' id='ticket' name='ticket'/></td>
<td><textarea id='report' name='report'>enter text report</textarea></t
```

here is my controller

```
function testUpload(){
    $data=array(
        'ticket'=>$this->input->post('ticket'),
        'report'=>$report=$this->input->post('repost')
    );
    $this->load->model('patient_model');
    $this->patient_model->insertReport($data);
}
```

and here is my model

```
function insertReport($data){
    $this->db->insert('report',$data);
}
```

Comment: `$this->input->post('repost')`.... **repost**? or `report`?

Answer (score 4):

Try below code, change `repost` to `report`

```
function testUpload(){
        $data=array(
        'ticket'=>$this->input->post('ticket'),
        'report'=>$report=$this->input->post('report')
        );

    $this->load->model('patient_model');
    $this->patient_model->insertReport($data);
}
```

**EDIT :-**

Seems like you have edited your question,

Initially it was `'report'=>$report=$this->input->post('tr')`

Now you have change`'report'=>$report=$this->input->post('repost')`

Both are wrong...

Comment: This appears to be a game of spot-the-difference…

Comment: @Quentin you are right, but initially he has mentioned `post('report')' as `post('tr')`

Comment: It's usually helpful to describe the changes rather than just rewriting the code though — especially when it is as subtle a change as 'repost'/'report'

Comment: I understand @Quentin ..  I will make sure next time :)

Answer (score 2):

You have `name='report'` but `$this->input->post('repost')`

You need to avoid making typos when referencing your field.

Answer (score 2):

Please Change `repost` to `report`

Because your textarea name is report

So, your controller should like the following...

```
function testUpload(){
    $data=array(
        'ticket'=>$this->input->post('ticket'),
        'report'=>$report=$this->input->post('report')
    );
    $this->load->model('patient_model');
    $this->patient_model->insertReport($data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
function testUpload(){
    $data=array(
        'ticket'=>$this->input->post('ticket'),
        'report'=>$this->input->post('report')
    );
    $this->load->model('patient_model');
    $this->patient_model->insertReport($data);
}
```

And you must sure in table report must exist field report.